# Angular 5 - Checking for server errors

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Probably this is not very hard but i dont know how to do it, i just started programming.

ItemDeleteComponent is a Are you sure you want to delete, Yes or No, in YES i want to show the snackbar Deleted! that's fine but in 'NO' i don't want to show the message Failed the message failed i want to show when something went wrong with server. i don't know how to do someone explain to me step by step.
Hope you understood me :)

```
onDeleteItem(item: Item) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ItemDeleteComponent, {
      width: '30%',
      data: {item: item.id}
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (!result) {
        this.matSnackBar.open('Deleted!', 'OK', {
          duration: 2000,
        });
      } 
      else {
        this.matSnackBar.open('Failed', 'OK', {
          duration: 2000,
        });
      }
   }
}
```

ItemDeleteComponent:

Yes:

```
async onDeleteArtisti(id: number) {
await this.apiService.deleteArtist(id).toPromise();
  this.dialogRef.close(); }
```

No:

```
  closeDialog() {
this.dialogRef.close(); }
```

Comment: You have aslo started to use StackOverflow - paste and format code in code block.

Comment: Also there is no such syntax as `if (variable){} else (variable){}` that rly compiles?

Comment: You have to show us how you actually closing your dialog (meaning, how you react on YES/NO buttons). So actual dialog code would be the best

Comment: In dialog yes/no code, where you are closing the dialog, you can pass dialog result - that value will be emitted in `afterClosed` observable, meaning that you can now check for ther result, and eg if (result==='Deleted') do this, else if(result==='serverError') show error else ....

Comment: i added the code of yes/no component

Comment: @xagnt can you paste this line in your afterClosed()
 `console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);` and tell me what does your console prints

Comment: `this.dialogRef.close(putYourResultValueHere);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you base your snack bar logic on the result of your dialog close action (the code is not shown, but I suspect the 'result' variable returned by the `dialogRef.afterClosed()` Observable represent the positive/negative action of your dialog).

If you want to base your snack bar logic on the results of your server request, you better subscribe to the Promise result when you make the api call:

```
onDeleteArtisti(id: number) {
  this.apiService.deleteArtist(id).toPromise()
   .then(success => this.matSnackBar.open('Deleted!', 'OK', {
          duration: 2000,
        }), error => this.matSnackBar.open('Failed', 'OK', {
          duration: 2000,
        })
   );
   this.dialogRef.close(); 
}
```

For more information, check the documentation on Promise and Observables:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Also check the documentation of your dialog component to understand what is the value returned by the `dialogRef.afterClosed()` observable.

Comment: thanks cghislai it worked with ur method :) sry i forgot to thank you